# Which event can be used for dropdown selected

Tags: jquery, html, events, dropdown

I have a drop down. which have some values. one value is taken from database and match with the values in `drodown`. If anyone matches, it will be set as `selected` automatically. now i can't use `onclick`,`onchange`,`onselect` because i don't have any actions. It is automatically selected. so which event can be used here? Any idea?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking how to detect when JavaScript changes the selected option?

Comment: Events generally aren't triggered when the properties are changed by code, only in response to external actions. Just have the code that changes the selected option also call the function that needs to react to the change.

Comment: i will explain. I have two dropdown menus. one is L1 and other one is L2. L1 is main and L2 is sub. If L1 is selected, all values under L1 should list in L2. This works fine in purchase. but when purchase edit is doing, one L1 will be selected automatically without any external actions. and i want L2 to list all under the selected L1

Comment: The code that selects the element from `L1` automatically can call `$("#L1").change()` to trigger the same action that occurs when the user changes the dropdown manually.